# Why is it possible to use loaded functions along with variables of the same names if the latter do not point to other functions?

Tags: r

In the session below, I define the variables `c` and `print` without any side effects, i.e. the `c` and `print` functions are still available along with the variables of the same name:

```
R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10) -- "One Push-Up"
Copyright (C) 2022 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

> typeof(c)
[1] "builtin"
> typeof(print)
[1] "closure"

> c <- 42
> print <- 'hello world'
> typeof(c)
[1] "double"
> typeof(print)
[1] "character"

> print(c(print, c))
[1] "hello world" "42"
```

But if I define a new *function* `c`, the new one is used now instead of `base::c`:

```
> c <- function(x, ...) paste('Hello', x, ...)
> c(1,2,3)
[1] "Hello 1 2 3"
> base::c(1,2,3)
[1] 1 2 3
> c <- "Gibberish"
> c(1,2,3)
[1] 1 2 3
```

Why don't the local variables `c` and `print` hide functions of the same name unless they point to some other user-defined procedures?

Comment: Your user defined variables have a different namespace to the functions from `Base` or other packages.  In other words, you can't have two objects with the same name *in the same environment*.
See: https://adv-r.hadley.nz/environments.html

Comment: The parser can identify that `c(1, 2, 3)` is a _call_, and it therefore only looks for a _function_ called `c` in the search path. It will ignore any variable that does not have the storage mode of "function" even if the variable has the same name. Therefore, a _function_ called `c` in the global environment will mask `base::c`, but a character variable called `c` will not.